# How to pass a session value as request parameter from JSP to servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```html
<c:forEach var="it" items="${sessionScope.projDetails}">
    <tr>
        <td>${it.pname}</td>
        <td>${it.pID}</td>
        <td>${it.fdate}</td>
        <td>${it.tdate}</td>
        <td> <a href="${it.address}" target="_blank">Related Documents</a></td>
        <td>${it.pdesc}</td>
        <form name="myForm" action="showProj">
            <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="${it.pID}" value="View Team">
            </td>
        </form>
</c:forEach>
```

Referring to the above code, I am getting session object `projDetails` from some servlet, and displaying its contents in a JSP. Since arraylist `projDetails` have more than one records the field `pID` also assumes different value, and the display will be a table with many rows.
Now I want to call a servlet `showProj` when the user clicks on "View Team" (which will be in each row) based on the that row's "pID".
Could someone please let me know how to pass the particular `pID` which the user clicks on JSP to servlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an `<input>` for each different pID, you could use links to pass the pID as a query string to the servlet, something like:

```
<a href="/showProj?pID=${it.pID}">View Team</a>
```

In the `showProj` servlet code, you'll access the query string via the `request` object inside a `doGet` method, something like:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String pID = request.getParameter("pID");
    //more code...
}
```

Here are some references for Java servlets:

[HttpServletRequest object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) 
 
[Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Comment: I tried the above code, but it says "The requested resource is not available" even after giving full URL of the servlet, I doubt whether we access the servlet through "href" in JSP??

Comment: You certainly can access a servlet via a regular `<a href=...>`. My first thought is that you haven't set up a `<servlet-mapping>` in your web.xml. There are a number of questions on SO that deal with this, or see "Servlet Basics" in the second link I provided above, which deals with "Giving URLs to Servlets"

Comment: It works now, i just put a "." in 
<a href="/.showProj?> Thanks a lot

Comment: hello i have a similar situation where i want to pass the complete list to the url for eg. in this case pass the project details attribute itself.  Can I append the list as a parameter itself in the url?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `pID` along in a hidden input field.

```html
<td>
    <form action="showProj">
        <input type="hidden" name="pID" value="${it.pID}">
        <input type="submit" value="View Team">
    </form>
</td>
```

*(please note that I rearranged the `<form>` with the `<td>` to make it valid HTML and I also removed the `id` from the button as it's invalid in HTML to have multiple elements with the same `id`)*

This way you can get it in the servlet as follows:

```
String pID = request.getParameter("pID");
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Define onclick function on the button and pass the parameter

```
<form name="myForm" action="showProj">
       <input type='hidden' id='pId' name='pId'>
       <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="${it.pID}" value="View Team" onclick="populatePid(this.name)">
       </td>
.....
```

Define javascript function:

```
function populatePid(name) {
  document.getElementById('pId') = name;
}
```

and in the servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String pID = request.getParameter("pId");
    .......
}
```

Comment: I tried with the above code but the "pID" in servlet contains "null"

Comment: Just want to point out, though not sure if that is a problem, that do take care of the variable names. The 'name' attribute of the 'hidden' should be the one you should be using in the servlet to get the value which in the above case is 'pId'. FInally, you will see request parameter being populated in the url when you submit the form e.g. xxx.com?pId=abc. If that happens it is certain that servlet will be getting value abc under the name pId. If that doesn't happens then there is a problem with HTML / JS code.

Comment: Am getting this when i submit the form "/showProj?pId=&445=View+Team", I have put the "String pID = request.getParameter("pId");" inside 
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
String pID = req.getParameter("pId");
........}
I got pID as null..
and after your comments i have tried putting the "String pID = request.getParameter("pId");" inside 
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
String pID=req.getParameter("pId")
......}

Comment: and am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed"

Comment: '/showProj?pId=&445=View+Team' shows that no value is being sent for pId. You need to check your html / JS code as to why this is happening

Comment: and am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException this has nothing to do with the code given above. Check this link out for a reason why this map happen: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/288524

Comment: <Script type="text/javascript">function populatePid(name) {document.getElementById('pId')=name;}
</Script>
<center><h1>Project Details</h1>
<table border="3">
<tr>
<th>
PName
</th>
<th>
PID
</th>
<th>
FDate
</th>
<th>
TDate
</th>
<th>
links
</th>
<th>
Project Desc
</th>
<th>
Team
</th>
</tr><c:forEach var="it" items="${sessionScope.projDetails}">
<tr>
<td>${it.pname}</td>
<td>${it.pID}</td>
<td>${it.fdate}</td>
<td>${it.tdate}</td>
<td> <a href="${it.address}" target="_blank">Related Documents</a></td>
<td>${it.pdesc}</td>

Comment: <form name="myForm" action="showProj">
<input type='hidden' id='pId' name='pId'>
<td><input id="button" type="submit" name="${it.pID}" value="View Team" onclick="populatePid(this.name)"></td>
</form> 
</c:forEach>
</table></center>